# How to prove that two waveforms are rectangular (quotient zero)?

Tags: integration

The problem is the following:

Prove that, when Δf = integer multiple of $\frac{2}{T}$, the waveforms:

$s_m(t) = A\cos(2πf_ct + 2πmΔft)$, for $m = 0, 1, ..., M - 1$ and $0 \le t \le T$

and

$s_m(t) = 0$, for $0 > t$ or $t > T$

with different value of $m$ are rectangular with each other.

[EDIT]
$f_c = \frac{1}{T}$, since it's the frequency, I guess.
[/EDIT]

I know that this means that it is enough for me to prove the following:

Let $s_{m1}(t)$ and $s_{m2}(t)$ to be two waveforms of the above description, then I have to show this:

$\int_0^T s_{m1}(t) * s_{m2}(t) dt = 0$

I am not sure if it's ok to pick just two of them and go on, but I think you will get the big picture.

With all these parameters and constants I am very confused and what I have tried doesn't seem to lead anywhere.

Any ideas?

---

[EDIT_2]

Let k be an integer. Since $f_c = \frac{1}{T}$ and $Δf = k *\frac{2}{T} = 2kf_c$

So, now, for $0 \le t \le T$, our waveform has this format:

$s_m(t) = Acos(2πf_ct(1 + 2κm)$

Now I need to take two waveforms with different $m$. I thought of that the first waveform would have $m_1 = m$ and the second $m_2 = m+1$, but I think that I am breaking the generality now? So I just left $m_1$ and $m_2$ in the waveforms, $s_{m1}(t)$ and $s_{m2}(t)$.

So, now we need to show the following and we are done:

$\int_0^T s_{m1}(t) * s_{m2}(t) dt = 0$

I used this rule:

$\cos(a) * \cos(b) = \frac{\cos(a+b)}{2} + \frac{\cos(a-b)}{2}$ and if I have no mistake, our integral is this now:

$\frac{A^2}{2}\int_0^T \cos(4πf_ct(1+km_1+km_2)) +  \cos(4πf_ct(km_1-km_2)) dt = 0$

and now I am not sure how to continue.

[/EDIT_2]

---

[EDIT_3]

$\frac{A^2}{2}\int_0^T \cos(4πf_ct(1+km_1+km_2)) +  \cos(4πf_ct(km_1-km_2)) dt = 0$

I am stuck here, any idea? I think I answered the question.

[/EDIT_3]

Comment: @byronschmuland, any idea why my question has no action?

Comment: I suspect that people are confused by all the notation,
 missing information, and the fact that you seem to have copied out the 
problem incorrectly. For example, if $T=1$ then 
all the functions $s_m(t)$ are identical because the 
cosine function is $2\pi$ periodic. This means that 
the exercise, as stated, is wrong.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland, what other information should I include? I had forgotten a term, in the second operand of the addition. Maybe now it's cleared? All the notation bothers me too. :/

Comment: The notation $m = 0, 1, ..., M - 1 \le t \le T$ looks strange. Is the value $t$ supposed to be bigger than $M-1$?? Anyway, my advice is to copy the problem out exactly, including all information, variables, notation, and punctuation. This will give people a better idea what the problem is.

Comment: This is what I am doing @ByronSchmuland! I think this is a mistake in the exercise. It would have more sense, if m = [0, M- 1] and 0 <= t <= T. Probably a typo of the ex., I am editing.

Comment: Have you left out any information on the value $f_c$? As it stands, the exercise is still wrong.

Comment: There is nothing about it @ByronSchmuland. Maybe it gets simplified when we perform the multiplication?

Comment: I found another typo...The correct is 0>t or t>T,

Comment: @ByronSchmuland $f_c$ must be the frequency, I think!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral, let's name it I, goes like this:

$I = \frac{A^2}{2}\int_0^T \cos(4πf_ct(1+km_1+km_2)) +  \cos(4πf_ct(km_1-km_2)) dt = $

$I = \frac{A^2}{2}[\frac{\sin(4πf_cT(1+km_1+km_2))}{4πf_c(1+km_1+km_2)} +  \frac{\sin(4πf_cT(km_1-km_2))}{4πf_c(km_1-km_2)} dt -0 - 0] $

The zeroes came from $\sin(0)$. Now, because $f_c = \frac{1}{T}$, we have:

$I=\frac{A^2}{2}[\frac{\sin(4π(1+km_1+km_2))}{4πf_c(1+km_1+km_2)} +  \frac{\sin(4π(km_1-km_2))}{4πf_c(km_1-km_2)} dt] $

Now, because $ sin(2π*any\_integer)=0$, we have:

$I = \frac{A^2}{2}[0 + 0] = 0, $thus $ I = 0$.